# Find two worst values and delete in sum

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32

A microcontroller has the job to sample ADC Values (Analog to Digital Conversion). Since these parts are affected by tolerance and noise, the accuracy can be significantly increased by deleting the 4 worst values. The find and delete does take time, which is not ideal, since it will increase the cycle time.

Imagine a frequency of 100MHz, so each command of software does take 10ns to process, the more commands, the longer the controller is blocked from doing the next set of samples

So my goal is to do the sorting process as fast as possible for this i currently use this code, but this does only delete the two worst!

```
uint16_t getValue(void){

    adcval[8] = {};
    uint16_t min = 16383 //14bit full
    uint16_t max = 1;    //zero is physically almost impossible!
    uint32_t sum = 0;    //variable for the summing

    for(uint8_t i=0; i<8;i++){
     if(adc[i] > max) max = adc[i];
     if(adc[i] < min) min = adc[i];
     sum=sum+adcval[i];
    }
    uint16_t result = (sum-max-min)/6;   //remove two worst and divide by 6
    return result;
}
```

Now I would like to extend this function to delete the 4 worst values out of the 8 samples to get more precision. Any advice on how to do this?

Additionally, it would be wonderful to build an efficient function that finds the most deviating values, instead of the highest and lowest. For example, imagine the this two arrays

```
uint16_t adc1[8] {5,6,10,11,11,12,20,22};
uint16_t adc2[8] {5,6,7,7,10,11,15,16};
```

First case would gain precision by the described mechanism (delete the 4 worst). But the second case would have deleted the values 5 and 6 as well as 15 and 16. But this would theoretically make the calculation worse, since deleting 10,11,15,16 would be better. Is there any fast solution of deleting the 4 most deviating?

Comment: Is it always ignore 4 values from a set of 8? You don't need a full sort, you just need to identify the 2 greatest and 2 smallest values

Comment: Aside: what does `adcval[8] = {};` do? Is it a kind of shorthand to say you collect 8 readings?

Comment: Your second question, to find the 2 most deviating values could be done by first averaging all 8, and then find the 2 that are furthest from the average, and recalculate a new average. It is not exactly "deviation", more a variation. Personally, I would not discard half of the readings, but halve the ADC conversion rate to make it more accurate. And as you are blocking the converter during your analysis, isn't it counter-productive? Perhaps what you need is a better *filter* algorithm, and take samples as fast as possible.

Comment: Deleting the highest and lowest recorded value(s) is not a good filtering mechanism unless you can demonstrate that your reading has no bias towards either end. In your last paragraph: why would deleting 10,11[,15,16] be better than deleting 5,6[,15,16]? You need to establish that first - and maybe describe your actual measurement setup.

Comment: @WeatherVane the ADC is oparated at a lower rate than it can be (1MSPS instead of 4), but the deviations usually come from noise etc.

Comment: @markus-nm  imagine the the perfect value, lets say its 10. Now there are several factors of deviation, first of all, the adc has deviation, for example out of 5 x measuring a perfect signal of 10, it will possible do 9,9,10,10,11 this is just the way it is. The next thing is noise, maybe just in the moment of measuring, a spike of noise is rising the input from 10 to 15... etc. In 99% of the case, out of 8 measurements, the ones that are the closest are correct ones

Comment: I used to use a *threshold*. If the input differed by more than a certain amount from the current average, it would need *n* more agreeing readings to be accepted, i.e. it was not a spike.

Comment: @sgt_johnny *he ones that are the closest are correct ones* then you should average your data set and remove some portion of the data which have the biggest difference to the average - but not simply N data from the lower and higher end. On another note, if your adc really outputs values like your adc1[8] or adc2[8] arrays, where the max can be 300% of the min, its probably misconfigured or damaged, or you really do have a **lot** of noise in your system.

Comment: You seem to be taking 1MSPS (which I assume is 1 million samples per second) and then averaging 8 at a time to produce a 125KSPS noise-reduced reading.  What is the maximum frequency of the signal you are trying to measure ?  If the noise is random, and averaging 8 samples is not enough, does that mean that the noise when it occurs is very loud indeed ?  In that case @WeatherVane is suggesting clipping big jumps compared to the previous sample, or the average of the last few samples... ie slew-rate limiting.  Running averages are easier than sorting !

Comment: What physical property is being measured?

Comment: The filtering method is wrong.  Use software low pass filter which will do the jobn for yuo.

Comment: Listen to P__J__, deleting the outermost values is not a **good** filter. If your really want to reduce noise then add better filtering and control on the outside of the MCU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If your ADC is returning values from 5 to 16 14 bits and the voltage reference 3.3V, the voltage varies from 1mV to 3mV. It is very likely that it is the correct reading. It is very difficult to design good input circuit for 14 bits ADC.
2. It is better to run the running average. What is the running average? It is software low pass filter.
   [image: x]
   Blue are readings from the ADC, red -running average

Second signal is the very low amplitude sine wave (9-27mV - assuming 14 bits and 3.3Vref)
[image]

The algorithm:

```
static int average;
int running_average(int val, int level)
{
    average -= average / level;
    average += val * level;
    return average / level;
}

void init_average(int val, int level)
{
    average = val * level;
}
```

if the `level` is the power of `2`. This version needs only 6 instructions (no branches) to calculate the average.

```
static int average;

int running_average(int val, int level)
{
    average -= average >> level;
    average += val << level;
    return average >> level;
}

void init_average(int val, int level)
{
    average = val << level;
}
```

I assume that average will no overflow. If yes you need to chose larger type

Comment: Sorry, the values i uses were examples, the true values will be different

Comment: OK, can you tell me where does level come from? I have array of values of 8 measures

Comment: Level is up to you.

Comment: Just to be sure, so in my case i would do a for loop and do 8 times:
running_average(adc[i],2); 

?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is kinda of topic as it recommends a hardware solution but if performance is required and the MCU can't implement P__J__'s solution than this is your next best thing.

It seems you want to remove noise from your input signal. This can be done in software using DSP ([digital signal processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processing)) **but** it can also be done by configuring your hardware differently.

By adding the proper filter at the proper space before your ADC, it will be possible to remove much (outside) noise from your ADC output. (you can't of course go below a certain amount that is innate in the ADC but alas.)

There are several q&a on [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=adc%20filter).

- One solution is adding a capacitor to filter some high frequency noise. As noted by [DerStorm8](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/419297/221951)
- [The Photon has another great solution here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/70092/221951) by suggesting RC, Sallen-Key and a cascade of Sallen-Key filters for a continuous signal filter.
- [Here (ADN007)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/adn007.pdf) is a Analog Design Note from Microchip on "Techniques that Reduce System Noise in ADC Circuits"

  > It may seem that designing a low noise, 12-bit Analog-to-Digital
  >   Converter (ADC) board or even a 10-bit board is easy. This is
  >   true, unless one ignores the basics of low noise design. For
  >   instance, one would think that most amplifiers and resistors work
  >   effectively in 12-bit or 10-bit environments. However, poor device
  >   selection becomes a major factor in the success or failure of the
  >   circuit. Another, often ignored, area that contributes a great deal
  >   of noise, is conducted noise. Conducted noise is already in the
  >   circuit board by the time the signal arrives at the input of the
  >   ADC. The most effective way to remove this noise is by using a
  >   low-pass (anti-aliasing) filter prior to the ADC. Including by-pass
  >   capacitors and using a ground plane will also eliminate this type
  >   of noise. A third source of noise is radiated noise. The major
  >   sources of this type of noise are Electromagnetic Interference
  >   (EMI) or capacitive coupling of signals from trace-to-trace.
  >   If all three of these issues are addressed, then it is true that
  >   designing a low noise 12-bit ADC board is easy.

  And their recommended solution path:

  > It is easy to design a true 12-bit ADC system by using a few
  >   key low noise guidelines. First, examine your devices (resistors
  >   and amplifiers) to make sure they are low noise. Second, use a
  >   ground plane whenever possible. Third, include a low-pass filter
  >   in the signal path if you are changing the signal from analog to
  >   digital. Finally, and always, include by-pass capacitors. These
  >   capacitors not only remove noise but also foster circuit stability.
- [Here](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/adc-input-noise.html#) is a good paper by Analog Devices on input noise. They note in here that "there are some instances where input noise can actually be helpful in achieving higher resolution."

  > All analog-to-digital converters (ADCs) have a certain amount of input-referred noise—modeled as a noise source connected in series with the input of a noise-free ADC. Input-referred noise is not to be confused with quantization noise, which is only of interest when an ADC is processing time-varying signals. In most cases, less input noise is better; however, there are some instances where input noise can actually be helpful in achieving higher resolution. If this doesn’t seem to make sense right now, read on to find out how some noise can be good noise.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a fixed size array, a hard-coded sorting network should be able to correctly sort the entire array with only 19 comparisons. Currently you have 8+2*8=24 comparisons already, although it is possible that the compiler unrolls the loop, leaving you with 16 comparisons. It is conceivable that, depending on the microcontroller hardware, a sorting network can be implemented with some degree of parallelism -- perhaps you also have to query the adc values sequentially which would give you opportunity to pre-sort them, while waiting for the comparison.

An optimal sorting network should be searchable online. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) has some pointers.

So, you would end up with some code like this:

```
sort_data(adcval);
return (adcval[2]+adcval[3]+adcval[4]+adcval[5])/4;
```

Update:

[image: sorting networks]

As you can take from this picture ([source](http://www.angelfire.com/blog/ronz/Articles/999SortingNetworksReferen.html)) of optimal sorting networks, a complete sort takes 19 comparisons. However 3 of those are not strictly needed if you only want to extract the middle 4 values. So you get down to 16 comparisons.

Comment: I get the point of paralellism, but at speed-adc's there is no wait time, since usually the mcu is the bottleneck, not the adc.
The conversion of samples will happen instantly, relative to cpu speed. The adc values are delivered from SPI, a Serial Protocol, each set of 16clocks, the adc will send out 16 data bits, one per clock. So there is no wait time between the conversions. You can send 100% clock cycles as long as you not reach the clock limit of 50Mhz.

Comment: @sgt_johnny You can get the number of comparisons down to 16. Which I believe you cannot get down much more. See my answer update.

Comment: those algorithms do not have too much sense, not very usable in DSP

Answer (score 0):

> to delete the 4 worst values out of the 8 samples

The methods are described on [geeksforgeeks k largest(or smallest) elements in an array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/) and you can implement the best method that suits you.

I decided to use [this good site](http://pages.ripco.net/~jgamble/nw.html) to generate best sorting algorithm with `SWAP()` macros needed to sort the array of 8 elements. Then I created a small C program that will test any combination of 8 element array on my sorting function. Then, because we only care of groups of 4 elements, I did something bruteforce - for each of the `SWAP()` macros I tried to comment the macro and see if the program still succeeds. I could comment 5 `SWAP` macros, leaving 14 comparisons needed to identify the smallest 4 elements in the array of 8 samples.

```
/**
 * Sorts the array, but only so that groups of 4 matter.
 * So group of 4 smallest elements and 4 biggest elements
 * will be sorted ok.
 * s[0]...s[3] will have lowest 4 elements
 *     so they have to be "deleted"
 * s[4]...s[7] will have the highest 4 values
 */
void sort_but_4_matter(int s[8]) {
#define SWAP(x, y)  do { \
        if (s[x] > s[y]) { \
            const int t = s[x]; \
            s[x] = s[y]; \
            s[y] = t; \
        } \
    } while(0)
    SWAP(0, 1);
    //SWAP(2, 3);
    SWAP(0, 2);
    //SWAP(1, 3);
    //SWAP(1, 2);
    SWAP(4, 5);
    SWAP(6, 7);
    SWAP(4, 6);
    SWAP(5, 7);
    //SWAP(5, 6);
    SWAP(0, 4);
    SWAP(1, 5);
    SWAP(1, 4);
    SWAP(2, 6);
    SWAP(3, 7);
    //SWAP(3, 6);
    SWAP(2, 4);
    SWAP(3, 5);
    SWAP(3, 4);
#undef SWAP
}

/* -------- testing code */

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int cmp_int(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(const int*)a - *(const int*)b;
}

void printit_arr(const int *arr, size_t n) {
    printf("{");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
        if (i != n - 1) {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("}");
}

void printit(const char *pre, const int arr[8], 
        const int in[8], const int res[4]) {
    printf("%s: ", pre);
    printit_arr(arr, 8);
    printf(" ");
    printit_arr(in, 8);
    printf(" ");
    printit_arr(res, 4);
    printf("\n");
}

int err = 0;
void test(const int arr[8], const int res[4]) {
    int in[8];
    memcpy(in, arr, sizeof(int) * 8);
    sort_but_4_matter(in);
    // sort for memcmp below
    qsort(in, 4, sizeof(int), cmp_int);
    if (memcmp(in, res, sizeof(int) * 4) != 0) {
        printit("T", arr, in, res);
        err = 1;
    }
}

void test_all_combinations() {
    const int result[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; // sorted
    const size_t n = 8;
    int num[8] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            int temp = num[i];
            num[i] = num[i+1];
            num[i+1] = temp;
            test(num, result);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    test_all_combinations();
    return err;
}
```

[Tested on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cyx5M5). The `sort_but_4_matter` with gcc -O2 on x86_64 compiles to less then 100 instruction.

Comment: but it is not to be going to be executed on x86.